# Can you deal with Ruby's method like functional programming, such as memoizing a function?

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, memoization

I could memoize a Ruby function, by using a local scope and a closure:

```
require "benchmark"

fib = ->(n) {
  return 0 if n < 0
  return 1 if n == 0
  return fib.(n-1) + fib.(n-2)
}

memoize = ->(f) {
  already_know = {}

  new_function = ->(n) {
    already_know[n] ||= f.(n)
    return already_know[n]
  }
  return new_function
}

fib = memoize.(fib)

puts Benchmark.measure { p fib.(42) }
```

and it took 0.000011 second to run.  Without the line `fib = memoize.(fib)`, it would take 259 seconds to run.

But can you do the same thing with a method (instead of a function) in Ruby?  It seems like a Python method is more like a function because you can easily do that with a Python method while a Ruby's method is less like a function -- maybe because a method in Ruby is not an object.  But the question is, can you do something like the `memoize` in the code above to make a method become memoized?

Comment: checkout [4 Simple Memoization Patterns in Ruby](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem/) using `@instance_variable`

Comment: I'm confused. You show Ruby (?) code to do a thing, and then ask how to do it in Ruby?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart it is function vs method

Comment: You can convert methods to to procs, e.g. `put_fn = Kernel.method(:puts).to_proc`.

Comment: @sschmeck can you use that and put in back to the class? (like redefining the method)

Answer (score 2):

You can alias the original method and add a simple caching to original implementation.

```
class Fib
  def fib(n)
    case
    when n < 0  then 0
    when n == 0 then 1
    else fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    end
  end
end
puts Benchmark.measure { p Fib.new.fib(35) }

class Fib
  alias_method :fib_ori, :fib

  def fib(n)
    (@fib_cache ||= {})[n] ||= fib_ori(n)
  end
end  
puts Benchmark.measure { p Fib.new.fib(35) }
```

Comment: seems like it works... not like functional programming... using an instance variable instead of a scope and a closure, but it works. If there is a solution that doesn't need to introduce an extra instance variable...

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [sschmeck's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34610636/477037), but via inheritance:

```
class Fibonacci
  def at(n)
    return 0 if n < 0
    return 1 if n == 0
    return at(n - 1) + at(n - 2)
  end
end

class MemoizedFibonacci < Fibonacci
  def initialize
    @memo = {}
  end
  def at(n)
    @memo[n] ||= super
  end
end
```

Comment: the last `return` in `at` method looks redundant :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko explicit `return` is sometimes used to improve readability even if it is syntactically unnecessary.

Comment: @naomik I am only 3 years with Ruby, but I've never seen someone intentionally use redundant `return`. For me personally it does not improve readability but hurts the eyes :)

Answer (score 1):

`Module#prepend` was added in Ruby 2+ specifically in because it can (among other things) act as a method combinator/decorator similar to CLOS or Python. In that way, you don't actually need to get access to the method itself, you can just override it.

```
class Module
  def memoize(meth)
    prepend(Module.new do
      memo = {}

      define_method(meth) do |*args, &blk|
        memo[[self, *args, blk]] ||= super(*args, &blk)
      end
    end)
  end
end

class Integer
  memoize def fib
    raise ArgumentError if self < 0
    return self if self < 2
    pred.fib + pred.pred.fib
  end
end

require 'benchmark'

puts Benchmark.measure { p 42.fib }
```

In older versions of Ruby (1.9 or older), you would have to do something like this:

```
class Module
  def memoize(meth)
    memo = {}
    old_meth = instance_method(meth)

    define_method(meth) do |*args, &blk|
      memo[[self, *args, blk]] ||= old_meth.bind(self).(*args, &blk)
    end
  end
end
```

Also, `def` evaluating to a `Symbol` denoting the name of the method being defined was added in Ruby 2.2, so, in older versions, you have to do this instead:

```
class Integer
  def fib
    raise ArgumentError if self < 0
    return self if self < 2
    pred.fib + pred.pred.fib
  end
  memoize :fib
end
```

We could use a trick such as the one Rake uses for its `desc` method, though, to make it memoize the next method being defined:

```
class Module
  def memoize(meth=nil)
    return @__memoize_next_method__ = true unless meth
    memo = {}
    old_meth = instance_method(meth)

    define_method(meth) do |*args, &blk|
      memo[[self, *args, blk]] ||= old_meth.bind(self).(*args, &blk)
    end
  end

  def method_added(meth)
    return if @__recursing__
    @__recursing__ = true # protect against infinite recursion

    if @__memoize_next_method__
      memoize(meth)
      @__memoize_next_method__ = nil
    end

    @recursing = nil
  end
end

class Integer
  memoize
  def fib
    raise ArgumentError if self < 0
    return self if self < 2
    pred.fib + pred.pred.fib
  end
end
```